# Why can't Ubuntu 18.04 chroot into a qemu environment?

Tags: 18.04, chroot, qemu

I'm really struggling to understand what's to blame with chroot / qemu not work on Ubuntu 18.04.  Later editions work (definitely by 19.10) but under 18.04 I get:

```
cannot run command '/bin/sh' No such file or directory.
```

I can't work out what's actually broken.  I can invoke the armhf binaries without trying to chroot and everything works fine.  I can download an x86_64 equivalent for the same environment and chroot into it.  But I can't chroot into an armhf environment.

My first guess is that this is something changed with qemu.  [Ubuntu 18.04 has qemu 2.11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=qemu-user-static) where as [Ubuntu 19.10 has qemu 4.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&keywords=qemu-user-static).  But I see nothing about chroot mentioned in the [qemu change log](https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog).

**I really want to be able to fix this without fully upgrading the box to a non-LTS release**.  If I can patch just one thing (even "just" the kernel) then I'm comfortable doing this; but without knowing what's actually broken I'm just stumbling round in the dark.

---

To reproduce the error:

- install `qemu-user-static` on an x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static
  ```
- download an arm chroot environment (eg: [alpine mini root file system armhf](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/))

  ```
  wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/releases/armhf/alpine-minirootfs-3.11.3-armhf.tar.gz
  ```
- extract and chroot into the environment

  ```
  mkdir my_env
  cd my_env
  tar -xf ../alpine-minirootfs-3.11.3-armhf.tar.gz
  chroot . /bin/sh
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed one step - you need to copy `qemu-arm-static` executable to the ARMhf filesystem.

So the steps below should work:

```
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/releases/armhf/alpine-minirootfs-3.11.3-armhf.tar.gz
mkdir my_env
cd my_env
tar -xf ../alpine-minirootfs-3.11.3-armhf.tar.gz
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static ./usr/bin/ # this is essential step!
sudo chroot . /bin/sh
```

And you will be able to run commands inside this chroot, for example:

> ```
> # arch
> armv7l
> ```

---

Notes:

1. I have tested this method on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS. It is based on my other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006847/66509).
2. Just tested chroot'ing from upcoming 20.04 LTS - is does not need copying of `qemu-arm-static`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I found the work around earlier today. To be clear though... This doesn't appear to be necessary in later versions of Ubuntu. I'm now thinking this is a change in the kernel but I don't see any mention of it in kernel change logs.

Comment: Other possibility is to have `binfmt-support` package installed. When testing this first time I have used https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static#chroot_in_to_the_image as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This difference is due to a new feature added to the kernel:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man8/update-binfmts.8.html

```
--fix-binary yes, --fix-binary no
           Whether to open the interpreter binary immediately and always use the opened image.
           This allows the interpreter from the host to be used regardless of usage in chroots or
           different mount namespaces.  The default behaviour is no, meaning that the kernel
           should open the interpreter binary lazily when needed.  This option requires Linux 4.8
           or newer.  It cannot be used together with --detector, or with multiple binary formats
           that share the same magic number, since the kernel will only open a single interpreter
           binary which will then not be able to detect and execute the real interpreter from
           inside a chroot or from a different mount namespace.
```

As this option is necessary to work properly with chroot and was only introduced in kernel 4.8 (Ubuntu 18.04 has only 4.15) getting this to work as described in my question requires a kernel upgrade.

There is of course [a workaround as mentioned in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204465/39039) where you copy qemu-arm-statick into your chroot environment.  For this to work it must be in the same location in the chroot environment as it is on your host.  Eg:

```
qemu=$(which qemu-arm-static)
cp ${qemu} ${target}/${qemu}
chroot ${target} /bin/sh
```

---

#### I haven't tested this yet but...

It looks like you can patch this by installing `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`.  see here for details on kernels from LTS Enablement:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack